# Material UI Popper over TextField how to keep popper open if the popper options are selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React Material UI, and I have a Textfield which if I focus on it will deploy a Popper with a simple Menu. If the Textfield loses the focus then the Popper closes itself. The thing is I need to select any option from the menu without close the Popper, but when I do that the Textfield loses the focus. What I need is to keep the Popper on only if I click outside of the Textfield or the Menu.

Everything is on this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-ride-fffh2?file=/src/MyApp.js).

I tried this:

```
const selected = prop => {
   console.log(prop);
}

...

        <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.paper}>
          <MenuList>
            <MenuItem onClick={() => selected('first')}>
              First Option
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={() => selected('next')}>
              Next Option
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={() => selected('last')}>
              And Last Option
            </MenuItem>
          </MenuList>
        </Paper>
      </Popper>
```

Also tried with `ClickAwayListener` wrapping both components, the TextField and the Popper:

```
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={blur}>
  <>
    <TextField ... />
    <Popper ...>
     ...
    </Popper>
  </>
</ClickAwayListener>
```

Unsuccessfully both times... How can I achieve this?

Comment: Isn't it better to implement this using the `Autocomplete` component of Material-UI?

Comment: @Dekel, nop... I need it to be done this way. I am not using Autocomplete since I need to keep the rest of the Component available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to implement this using the Autocomplete, but since the OP requested another solution - here is another option:

Once blur - check the element that caused the blur. If that element is one of the items in the popper - don't blur:

```
if (e.relatedTarget && e.relatedTarget.classList.contains("MuiListItem-root")) {
    return;
}
```

The full blur function will look like this:

```
const blur = (e) => {
    if (e.relatedTarget && e.relatedTarget.classList.contains("MuiListItem-root")) {
        e.target.focus();
        return;
    }
    setAnchorEl(null);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Although the solution by @Dekel is working well enough.
But **in my opinion,** it would be better if we would use React.useRef() for focusing on the text field.

Here is the updated solution link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-frost-bb88l?file=/src/MyApp.js

```
const textFieldRef = React.useRef();
```

Inside return ()

```
<TextField
  aria-describedby={id}
  onFocus={focus}
  onBlur={blur}
  placeholder="Focus on me"
  inputRef={textFieldRef}
/>
```

On selecting any menu list item

```
const selected = event => {
  console.log("Selected ", event.target.innerText);
  textFieldRef.current.focus();
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to dig in the hooks a little more.